# Cheatsheet for Android programming?

Tags: android

Is there any cheat sheet available for Android programming. Most commonly used classes with package description, just like a reference sheet would be nice.

Comment: http://d.android.com/reference/packages.html There you go.

Comment: illojal - correction - its actually here http://source.android.com/download

Comment: I would love a Quick Reference Card for Android Programming. The thing I miss the most is a short list of Functions I could overwrite in my activities to achieve certain things.

I could't find something on google until now.

Comment: @AlexVolovoy Your link is not longer valid. Can you update it?

Comment: This might be a good candidate for the Documentation sister site.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For a concise list of Android recipes check out [Damon Kohler's blog](http://www.damonkohler.com/2009/02/android-recipes.html).  He covers Intents, Wifi, Notifications, Alerts, Location, SMS, and Sensors in less than four pages.

Answer (score 11):

I think [this](http://refcardz.dzone.com/refcardz/android-application) could be useful.

It's a brief summary, but could be interesting.

Comment: +1 I think this should be the accepted answer.. I guess, people haven't gone through this cheatsheet... Anyways, thanks.. It helped me a lot..

Answer (score 7):

Here is a list of [common tasks](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/faq/commontasks.html) on the android platform, each has an explanation and typically an example.

Answer (score 3):

I made this one based on my notes from getting started:

http://francisshanahan.com/index.php/2011/android-development-cheatsheet/

Answer (score 2):

Check out android development fundementals. The activity lifecycle section describes the methods to override in an activity. [Activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#actlife)